# How to remotely generate Windows AD Kerberos keytab from a Unix machine?

Tags: active-directory, windows, kerberos

I would like to know if it’s possible to create a keytab file direct from a client machine without using the `ktpass` utility in the Windows Server side.

The main reason I would want this, is to automatically enable the integration of Kerberos authentication from Windows Active Directory in Linux machines using some shell scripts.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you’re running a Linux system, or any SAMBA compatible system, you can use the `net` application to join the domain and remotely generate the keytab for you, and since you’re working in a “Kerberized” environment I would use Kerberos to make all the authentication.

First of all ask a Kerberos Ticket from the Windows KDC with any privileged account:

```
kinit Administrator
```

You can check if the ticket was successfully generated with `klist` and after the ticket creation, just join the domain using the `net` application:

```
net ads join createupn=host/your_hostname.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM -k
```

When the procedure is complete, just ask the KDC to create a keytab:

```
net ads keytab create -k
```

You can finally check the keytab creation with `klist -ke` command if you’re using MIT Kerberos version.